# Eclipse slow at building Android resources

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build, ram

I'm using Eclipse to develop Android apps.
I'm using the latest SDK and Eclipse 3.6, my computer is macbook air with 4GB of ram.

Everytime I change a resource file ( an XML layout for example ), it takes eclipse between 1mn and 2mn to actually rebuild the binary and deploy it. My binary is about 10M ( it's a game with lots of bitmaps ).

It's very hard to program with such high response times, any way to make it shorter ?

Comment: AFAIK, the main reason it takes so long is that changing resources results in basically a full rebuild.  Changing java files will only rebuild what is necessary.

Comment: My build is also very slow. And I don't have lot's of PNGs. As far as I can see aapt.exe processes layout files for too long. The problem appeared in SDK 2.2. If I build with SDK 2.1 the build is very fast.

Comment: PNG solution is useless with me. I agree with Fedor and have the same experience on that. When I change to API level 7, building time is much less than before. In the meantime, you also sacrifice the capabilities in SDK 2.2, and that's really awful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a lot of graphics you might want to read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/DT-i8QK27Iw) android-dev post.  aapt optimizes pngs during a build (perhaps unnecessarily so) but only if the extension is .png (case sensitive).  Renaming them to .PNG skips the optimization step but the images are still useful when referenced.

Answer (score 3):

They are fixing this problem and it's available in ADT 12.

http://tools.android.com/download

http://tools.android.com/recent/finercontroloveradtbuildprocess

Comment: Awesome, I really hope this gets released soon!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using maven or such? Eclipse + Maven both have a builder, and they tend to fight a lot if both are enabled.

(honestly the best answer is use Intelli-J, and everything will magically work, but I doubt you want this answer).

Comment: do you have good tutorial for project with multi connected packages? I tried but after import i got (own work) few packages which some are libs and some other types and I have no idea what import and what which set.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the check Build Automatically in Project menu, in this way you are not continously compiling. In Android resources are highly optimized so compilation in an application like your can take time.

You can manually compile when you have done significant changes.

Answer (score 0):

ADT 14 will solve this.

http://tools.android.com/download/adt-14-preview